# Получаю такую ошибку sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Tags: java, android

Исходя из описания логов

> W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {3406a152} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {3406a152} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(Handler.java:623)
>                                                                                       at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.quit(RequestThreadManager.java:941)
>                                                                                       at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.close(LegacyCameraDevice.java:444)
>                                                                                       at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.finalize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:468)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   05-18 13:32:39.446 27812-27824/com.example.android.camera2basic W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {365dc23} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {365dc23} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(Handler.java:623)
>                                                                                       at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.quit(RequestThreadManager.java:941)
>                                                                                       at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.close(LegacyCameraDevice.java:444)
>                                                                                       at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.finalize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:468)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Это означает, что `Handler` уже прекратил существовать и какие то сообщения ему все еще долетают... Я так понял

Посоветуйте как отследить где точно ошибка? Я так понимаю, что нужно перед тем как уйти с активити прекратить выполнение какой то задачи которая бежит в бекграунде...

Что делать?

**Правка**
Метод закрытия камеры

```
private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        closeAllComponents();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
        cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}

protected final void closeAllComponents() throws InterruptedException {
    cameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
    closeCaptureSession();
    closeCameraDevice();
    closeImageReader();
}

private void closeCaptureSession() {
    if (null != captureSession) {
        captureSession.close();
        captureSession = null;
    }
}

private void closeCameraDevice() {
    if (null != cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
}


private void closeImageReader() {
    if (null != imageReader) {
        imageReader.close();
        imageReader = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я получал подобную  при многократном переключении с фронтальной на тыловую камеру.
У меня в closeCamera() не было такого :

```
  if(null!=mCameraCaptureSession){
       CameraCaptureSession.close();
       CameraCaptureSession= null;
}
```

а так же в closeCamera() постоянно вызывался `stopBackgroundThread()`;
Я переместил этот вызов в `onStop()` моего `CameraActivity` и добавил вышеописанные строки кода. В моем случае ошибка `sending message to a Handler on a dead thread` исчезла.  Судя по твоим логам, повидимому проблема в этом же методе. В любом случае рекомендую детальней ознакомиться с примером [camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) и стопать камеру так как указано там.

Comment: Да но у меня вроде с этим все в порядке... Добавил в вопрос